# How to access leaflet map passed using input?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

In my example I need to access `leaflet` map from module 2 (nested) and use `input$` on a map to return polygon coordinates. It works perfectly when I do this in my main module (module 1) where I can freely refer to 'map'. Unfortunately, when I pass map to another module (module 2) then the same trick with `input$` doesn't work at all. Do you know how to solve it?

Here is the reproducible example. Please draw rectangle on a map and see that no coordinates are returned to the text area. But if you uncomment my gray code (in module 1) then you will see all works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(mapboxer)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)


moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
  callModule(module, id)
}

# UI 1 #
mod_btn_UI1 <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("map")),
    mod_btn_UI2(ns("other")),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("selectedArea1"))    
  )
}

# Server 1 #
mod_btn_server1 <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
        
    coords <- quakes %>%
      sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
    
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
      leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
        leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
        leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
        leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
          data = coords,
          stroke = FALSE,
          radius = 6) %>% 
        leaflet.extras::addDrawToolbar()
    })
    
    # here I pass map id and session to module 2 and it works fine
    mod_btn_server2("other", "map", session)  
    
    # # the code below works fine - here I simply pass 'map' to input$
    #
    # polygon_coords <- reactive({input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]})
    # output$selectedArea1 <- renderPrint({
    #   print(polygon_coords())
    # })           
  })
}


# UI 2 #
mod_btn_UI2 <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("selectedArea2"))
  )
}

# Server 2 #
mod_btn_server2 <- function(id, mapPassed, parentSession){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
   
  # here input seems not working with 'mapPassed' as it does in module 1   
  polygon_coords <- reactive({input$mapPassed_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]})
    
     output$selectedArea2 <- renderPrint({
       print(polygon_coords())
     
   })
  })
}


# Final app #

ui <- fluidPage(  
  tagList(
    mod_btn_UI1("test-btn"))  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  mod_btn_server1("test-btn")  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the input name to the embedded module, you can pass it as a reactive:

```r
mod_btn_server2("other", 
                 reactive(input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]), 
                 session)
```

and you use it in the embedded module like any other reactive :

```r
polygon_coords <- reactive(mapPassed())
```

Comment: Very nice and tricky solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you use this kind of modularization, input, output and sessions module parameters are subsets of main input/output/session that correspond to the namespace created from module id (the NS function). If you create an input named dummy in a module whose id is foo then what is really created is an input named foo-dummy. So in the foo module you get as input all inputs having names starting with "foo-" and similarly all outputs starting with "foo-".

Comment: Ok, I try to visualize what you wrote having in mind my example but still don't know if it's possible to use `input` on passed map or not. Map which I passed works fine in `leafletProxy`. Map I'm passing refers to namespace from Module 1. Could you please give me example how should I implement it properly?